# I want to store Image in an excel sheet CSV but giving me this data:image/

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to store Image in an excel sheet CSV but giving me this `"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="` instead of image url

```py
class NewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "articles"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = input("Enter the article url: ")
        
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
    

        Feature_Image =response.xpath('//*[@id="article-wrapper"]/article/section[2]/div/div/div/img//@src').get()
        Feature_Image = response.urljoin(Feature_Image)

        yield{
        'Publication Date': Published_Date,
        'Feature_Image': Feature_Image,
        'Article Content': Content
        }
            # =============== Data Store +++++++++++++++++++++
        Data = [[Category,Headlines,Author,Source,Published_Date,Feature_Image,Content,url]]
        try:
            df = pd.DataFrame (Data, columns = ['Category','Headlines','Author','Source','Published_Date','Feature_Image','Content','URL'])
            print(df)
            with open('C:/Users/Public/pagedata.csv', 'a') as f:
                df.to_csv(f, header=False)
        except:
            df = pd.DataFrame (Data, columns = ['Category','Headlines','Author','Source','Published_Date','Feature_Image','Content','URL'])
            print(df)
            df.to_csv('C:/Users/Public/pagedata.csv', mode='a')
```

Comment: Would you share the url?then I could a bit try to solve it or open the csv file on the LibreOffice because it can handle unicode nicely

Comment: Sure, here it is " https://skift.com/2022/10/08/american-express-travels-rebound-and-other-top-stories-this-week/ "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The image url is absolute url. So no need to make it again absolute url using `urljoin()` method which is the main reason not to grab the original image url.
2. Your image url selected xpath expression select only a single image. So get rid of extra forward slash from @src
3. You aren't getting the right image url because @src select the image url that is your output but the original image url's attribute is `@data-src`

**Try:**

```
import scrapy

class NewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "articles"
    def start_requests(self):
        #https://skift.com/2022/10/08/american-express-travels-rebound-and-other-top-stories-this-week/
        url = input("Enter the article url: ")
        
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):

        Feature_Image =response.xpath('//*[@id="article-wrapper"]/article/section[2]/div/div/div/img/@data-src').get()

        yield {

            #'Publication Date': Published_Date,
            'Feature_Image': Feature_Image,
            #'Article Content': Content
            
            }
```

**Output:**

```
{'Feature_Image': 'https://skift.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/American_Express_office_in_Rome-1-e1665181357253-1024x682.jpg'}
```

Comment: Still getting this " data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==' "

I used this one this time " Feature_Image =response.xpath('//*[@id="article-wrapper"]/article/section[2]/div/div/div/img/@src').get() "

Comment: Ok wait I will  test it  and try to show the ooutput whatever I get

Comment: @Info Rewind, Please  see the updated Result

Comment: Really appreciate it, It worked, Thanks a lot. I searched a lot about this and try many solutions from the answers to StackOverflow listed questions related to this problem but fail to solve this every time, but only your answer worked for me.